# How to compare two dates in different formats

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone, datejs

I have a two dates in one format `19/02/2026, 07/02/2012` and third date in

```
2021-05-19T12:51:11.630Z
```

It's `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ`.
And i need to check third date if it is between those to dates.
But the problem is that i cannot find way how to do it with different formats.
I tried to use `moment()` `isBetween, isBefore(), isAfter()` functions but it didn't work correctly because of different formats

I tried to convert them all to miliseconds

```
moment('19/02/2026').valueOf()
```

But from time to time instead of miliseconds i recieve `NaaN` value.
I also tried to use

```
Date().parse()
```

But it gives `Invalid Date` most of the time.
I could do something like this, but i think it's wrong way.

```
let currentDate = moment( moment('2021-05-19T12:51:11.630Z').format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

Is there are any simple ways to do it with Date or moment ?

Comment: The main question is why do you get `NaN` or `Invalid Date` in some cases. The other cases shouldn't be a problem. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To parse a string which is not either an RFC2822 or ISO8601 format, you will need to specify the format to use:

```
const d = moment('19/02/2026', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Rather than using `valueOf`, you can test whether one `moment` instance is between two other `moment` instances by using `isBetween`:

```
const startDate = moment('07/02/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
const endDate = moment('19/02/2026', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
const dateToTest = moment('2021-05-19T12:51:11.630Z');
if (dateToTest.isBetween(startDate, endDate)) {
    alert("Between");
} else {
    alert("Not between");
}
```

[String + Format | Moment.js | Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)
[Is Between | Moment.js | Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although it didn't work. With those dates                         
2021-10-08T16:32:00.405Z
30 27/01/2013,   11/02/2027 
isBetween returns false

Comment: @Vlad Works fine for me: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/RichardD/r4t2ujm3/)